# Google colab issue importing ue using different class files

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to use Google colab for my project for which I have to upload a few python files because I need those class files.But while executing the main function.It is constantly throwing me an error 'module object has no attribute' . Is there some memory issue with colab or what! Help would be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import NN
import Option
import Log
import getData
import Quantize

 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NN'
```

I uploaded all files using following code :

```
from google.colab import files
src = list(files.upload().values())[0]
open('Option.py','wb').write(src)
import Option
```

But its always giving me error on some or the other files which I am importing.

Answer (score 0):

The updated version (for a few weeks) can save the files without you having to call `open(fname, 'wb').write(src)`

So, you only have to upload your 5 files: NN.py, Option.py, Log.py, getData.py, and Quantize.py (and probably other dependency + data) then try importing each one e.g. `import NN` to see if there's any error.

Comment: When you say upload what it means? Because what I was trying to do was to upload the files then use import for those class files. But it is always throwing the same error.

Comment: You can simplify the problem. Make a small library, upload it, import it, see if the same error happen.